# Firebase A/B testing - Know what group a user is in on device

Tags: firebase-analytics, mixpanel, firebase-ab-testing

We have an A/B test set up that runs on Firebase. To analyze events we are using Mixpanel instead of Firebase. Assume we have User1 and User2.

User1 gets assigned experiment group A and User2 gets assigned group B. Is there a way one can figure out which group a user has been assigned to and then send that information to Mixpanel as an event?